# Interrupting query sends wrong thread ID

Tags: mysql, client, command-line

In the MySQL command line client (Linux) when I kill a query by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> this usually works fine.

```
mysql (slave) > select sleep(5);
^CCtrl-C -- sending "KILL QUERY 117920686" to server ...
Ctrl-C -- query aborted.
+----------+
| sleep(5) |
+----------+
+----------+
1 row in set (0.78 sec)
```

However when I do the same on my live master server (of all servers it must be this one...) it somehow sends the wrong thread ID.

```
mysql (master) > select sleep(5);
^CCtrl-C -- sending "KILL QUERY 770543254" to server ...
Ctrl-C -- query aborted.
+----------+
| sleep(5) |
+----------+
+----------+
1 row in set (5.00 sec) /* <- it obviously hasn't aborted at all */
```

The ID is way too low. Other threads have IDs like 26534760326. All servers are of the same version:

```
# yum list installed mysql*
Loaded plugins: dellsysid, rhnplugin, security, ulninfo
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or Red Hat Satellite.
Installed Packages
MySQL-python.x86_64                                             1.2.3-0.3.c1.1.el6                              @public_ol6_latest
mysql-community-client.x86_64                                   5.6.27-2.el6                                    @mysql56-community
mysql-community-common.x86_64                                   5.6.27-2.el6                                    @mysql56-community
mysql-community-libs.x86_64                                     5.6.27-2.el6                                    @mysql56-community
mysql-community-libs-compat.x86_64                              5.6.27-2.el6                                    @mysql56-community
mysql-community-release.noarch                                  el6-5                                           @/mysql-community-release-el6-5.noarch
mysql-community-server.x86_64                                   5.6.27-2.el6                                    @mysql56-community
```

Additional info:

The [`connection_id()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_connection-id) function returns the right value however.

```
root@ods01:(none) > select connection_id();
+-----------------+
| connection_id() |
+-----------------+
|     26542310314 |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

root@ods01:(none) > select sleep(5);
^CCtrl-C -- sending "KILL QUERY 772506538" to server ...
Ctrl-C -- query aborted.
+----------+
| sleep(5) |
+----------+
+----------+
1 row in set (5.00 sec)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a bug report!  http://bugs.mysql.com.

```
  26542310314 MOD 2^32 = 772506538
```

That is, the 64-bit connection_id was chopped to 32 bits to send the KILL, thereby sending it to the wrong id.

Not many users get past 4 billion connections.  How long has your server been up?  I hope the code is not reconnecting for every query.

**Change logs**

> ----- 2014-09-25 5.7.5 Milestone 15 -- Bugs Fixed -- -----
>
> Connection IDs are 32-bit unsigned integers, beginning at 1. When the server assigns connection IDs and reaches the top of the 32-bit range, it rolls the value over to begin at 1 again. It was possible that the server would assign a connection ID to a new thread while that ID was still in use by an existing thread, if the old thread was particularly long running. For such cases, reference to the ID becomes ambiguous. For example, it cannot reliably be determined for [KILL connection_id](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/kill.html) which thread to kill, which could lead to undefined behavior. This behavior has been corrected so that in-use IDs are not reused.
> Connection IDs are 32-bit unsigned integers, beginning at 1. When the server assigns connection IDs and reaches the top of the 32-bit range, it rolls the value over to begin at 1 again. It was possible that the server would assign a connection ID to a new thread while that ID was still in use by an existing thread, if the old thread was particularly long running. For such cases, reference to the ID becomes ambiguous. For example, it cannot reliably be determined for [KILL connection_id](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/kill.html) which thread to kill, which could lead to undefined behavior. This behavior has been corrected so that in-use IDs are not reused.
>
> ----- 2012-12-11 5.6.9 Release Candidate -- Bugs Fixed -- Incompatible Change -----
>
> Connection ID (thread ID) values greater than 32 bits can occur on
> some systems (such as busy or long-running 64-bit systems), causing
> these problems:
>
> Connection IDs written to the general query log and slow query log
> were incorrect. This was true for logging to both files and tables.
>
> The
> [CONNECTION_ID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_connection-id)
> function could return a value with a data type too small for values
> larger than 32 bits.
>
> The
> [mysql_thread_id()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-thread-id.html)
> and
> [mysql_kill()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-kill.html)
> C API functions did not handle ID values larger than 32 bits. This
> could result in killing the wrong thread; for example, if you invoked
> mysql_kill(mysql_thread_id()).
>
> Connection IDs now are permitted to be 64-bit values when the server
> supports them (when built with 64-bit data types), which has these
> effects:
>
> Connection IDs are logged correctly to the general query log and slow
> query log.
>
> Note This change involves a modification to the log tables, so after
> upgrading to this release, you must run mysql_upgrade and restart the
> server.
>
> [CONNECTION_ID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_connection-id)
> returns a data type appropriate for values larger than 32 bits.
>
> [mysql_thread_id()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-thread-id.html)
> is unchanged; the client/server protocal has only 4 bytes for the ID
> value. This function returns an incorrect (truncated) value for
> connection IDs larger than 32 bits and should be avoided.
>
> [mysql_kill()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-kill.html)
> still cannot handle values larger than 32 bits, but to guard against
> killing the wrong thread now returns an error in these cases:
>
> If given an ID larger than 32 bits,
> [mysql_kill()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-kill.html)
> returns a
> [CR_INVALID_CONN_HANDLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-client.html#error_cr_invalid_conn_handle)
> error.
>
> After the server's internal thread ID counter reaches a value larger
> than 32 bits, it returns an
> [ER_DATA_OUT_OF_RANGE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_data_out_of_range)
> error for any
> [mysql_kill()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-kill.html)
> invocation and
> [mysql_kill()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-kill.html)
> fails.
>
> To avoid problems with
> [mysql_thread_id()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-thread-id.html)
> and
> [mysql_kill()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-kill.html),
> do not use them. To get the connection ID, execute a SELECT
> CONNECTION_ID() query and retrieve the result. To kill a thread,
> execute a KILL statement.
>
> (Bug #19806, Bug #11745768, Bug #65715, Bug #14236124, Bug #44728, Bug #11753308)

(Small bug numbers can be found at bugs.mysql.com; large bug numbers are inaccessible - internal to Oracle.)

So, recommend you upgrade to 5.6.9+ or 5.7.5+.  Since you are on 5.6.27, there is a puzzle.  Maybe some detail in that lengthy Changelog says something useful.

Comment: Good sleuthing.  The C client API structure for [`mysql_thread_id()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-thread-id.html) is 32 bits.  One would hope they took their own workaround advice (at the link) and fixed the `mysql` CLI at some point.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - Ouch.  That probably means that fixing it would involve an incompatibility.  Still, I think it deserves a bug report.  I've seen a machine do 400 Connections/sec; that would take 4 months to overflow 2^32.

Comment: I haven't looked into release notes or source, but they might have fixed this in a recent version of the CLI.  It could be fixed with a query to `SELECT CONNECTION_ID()`.

Comment: @RickJames Thanks for the research. We indeed had a problem with too many connections for a while, but it's been fixed. The server is running now for over 2 years.

Comment: @RickJames Filing a bug report is useless as I understand it. In 5.6.9 they just fixed, that the correct ID is written to general and slow log, but couldn't use a 64bit number because the client server protocol only allows 4 byte for that number. This seems to be such a big issue, that they implemented the roll over mechanism in 5.7.5. At least that's how I understand it.